# create table in hive with additional columns

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am new to Hive . I want to create the table in hive with the same columns as that of existing table plus some additional columns.  I Know we can use something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name
AS
SELECT *
FROM old_table_name
```

This will create the table with same columns as that of old_table_name.

But How do I specify additional columns in new_table_name ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve it:

> Old table:

```
hive> describe departments;
OK
department_id           int                     from deserializer   
department_name         string                  from deserializer
```

> Create table:

```
create table ctas as 
select department_id, department_name, 
cast(null as int) as col_null 
from departments;
```

> Displaying Structure of new table:

```
hive> describe ctas;
OK
department_id           int                                         
department_name         string                                      
col_null                int                                         
Time taken: 0.106 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

> Results from new table:

```
hive> select * from ctas;
OK
2       Fitness         NULL
3       Footwear        NULL
4       Apparel         NULL
5       Golf            NULL
6       Outdoors        NULL
7       Fan Shop        NULL
8       TESTING         NULL
8000    TESTING         NULL
9000    testing export  NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to issue `ALTER TABLE` command to add more(additional) columns after the above `CREATE` statement.

Comment: Thanks Murali . Is there any way , I can specify at the time of create itself ? If I go by Alter table suggestion , then adding few columns later , will it result in any mapreduce job  ? I am just trying to understand if there is any performance lose if we go by this approach

Comment: if your table already has data, and then you are trying to add a column, then it will not work as you ay need to rewrite the table with values in new columns. However, it is a blank table, then it is a simple alter, so should be light weight. Not sure if that will invoke a MR though.

Answer (score 0):

first create a new table like the first one
and after that alter this new table and add the columns that you want.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD COLUMNS (newCol1 int,newCol2 int);
```

if you wish to avoid data copy, make your table external

I wish that it helps you :)